# How to fix "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" and "excess elements in char array initializer" when setting up a 2D character array

Tags: c

I'm attempting to make a 2D array which would store a question and an answer in each row of the array, what do I need to do to set this up, as well as be able to call rows from this array.

I have tried to change the brackets to the right of the array name (eg. [15][2], [15], no brackets), and looked at a few stackoverflow problems which don't quite work for my problem. I am also getting the "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" error when on the 'H' case of the switch statement. I am also getting several "braces around scalar initializer", "excess elements in scalar initializer" and "makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" warnings during loading. I apologize if I made any obvious mistakes I'm coming to C from Python and still trying to wrap my head around it.

```
int trivia() {
    char history[15] = { {"Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III",}
                        {"Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther"},
                        {"Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo"},
                        {"What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans"},
                        {"What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols"},
                        {"Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage"},
                        {"What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas"},
                        {"What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf"},
                        {"What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia"},
                        {"Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein"},
                        {"What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo"},
                        {"What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun"},
                        {"Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland"},
                        {"What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek"},
                        {"For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion"}
                        };
char sport[15] = { {"Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III"},
                        {"Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther"},
                        {"Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo"},
                        {"What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans"},
                        {"What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols"},
                        {"Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage"},
                        {"What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas"},
                        {"What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf"},
                        {"What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia"},
                        {"Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein"},
                        {"What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo"},
                        {"What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun"},
                        {"Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland"},
                        {"What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek"},
                        {"For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion"}
                        };
char geography[15] = { {"Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III"},
                        {"Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther"},
                        {"Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo"},
                        {"What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans"},
                        {"What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols"},
                        {"Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage"},
                        {"What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas"},
                        {"What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf"},
                        {"What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia"},
                        {"Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein"},
                        {"What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo"},
                        {"What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun"},
                        {"Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland"},
                        {"What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek"},
                        {"For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion"}
                        };
char technology[15] = { {"Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III"},
                        {"Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther"},
                        {"Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo"},
                        {"What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans"},
                        {"What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols"},
                        {"Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage"},
                        {"What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas"},
                        {"What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf"},
                        {"What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia"},
                        {"Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein"},
                        {"What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo"},
                        {"What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun"},
                        {"Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland"},
                        {"What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek"},
                        {"For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion"}
                        };
char y;
char a[2];
char answer;
int g, i = 0, points = 0;
printf("This is a trivia game, choose from History, Geography, Sport or Technology \nThere will be 5 random questions, and the user will have to enter the correct answer.\nThe user will be scored out of 5 at the end. \nPlease enter G, H, S, or T to choose which set of questions.");
scanf("%c", &y);
switch(y){
    case 'H' :
        while (i<5){
            g = (rand() % (15 + 1 - 1) + 1);
            a[1] = history[g][1];
            a[2] = history[g][2];
            printf("%c", a[1]);
            printf("What is your answer");
            scanf("%c", &answer);
            if (answer == a[2]){
                printf("Correct! 1 point");
                points++;
            } else {
                printf("Incorrect! 0 points");
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("You got %d points.", &points);
        menu();
        break;
    case 'G' :
        break;
    case 'S' :
        break;
    case 'T' :
        break;
    default:
        printf("That was an incorrect input.");
        trivia();
return 0;
```

I am expecting the program to build, then to be able to run through the H case and give me points based on how many correct answers I got.

Comment: The initializers are for arrays of arrays. But the types are simple 1D arrays.

Comment: A string is an array of chars. Your variables are simple (and very short) strings, not arrays of strings.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define 2D arrays of strings, which would correspond to 3D arrays of chars (or 2D arrays of pointers to chars).

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1 (even in Python).

Comment: There is too much wrong with this snippet for a simple answer. You need to read a good introduction to C.

Comment: @xing That's just papering over the problem. OP intends `answer` to be a string (likely a full line of user input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @usr mentioned in its Answer, probably it is better for you to use an Array of Pointers for this task.

Here is an Example of one of your Arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define GETLEN(array) sizeof array / sizeof array[ 0 ]
const char *separator   ( const size_t num );

int main( void )
{
    const char *history[] =
    {
        "Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III",
        "Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther",
        "Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo",
        "What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans",
        "What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols",
        "Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage",
        "What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas",
        "What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf",
        "What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia",
        "Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein",
        "What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo",
        "What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun",
        "Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland",
        "What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek",
        "For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion",
    };
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < GETLEN( history ) ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%s%s\n", separator(i), history[i] );
    }
}

const char *separator ( const size_t num )
{
    if ( num % 2 == 0 )
    {
        return "Question:\t";
    }
    return "Answer:\t\t";
}
```

Output:

```
Question:   Which English king was "mad"?
Answer:     George III
Question:   Who started the Protestant Reformation?
Answer:     Martin Luther
Question:   Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?
Answer:     Galileo
Question:   What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?
Answer:     The Normans
Question:   What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?
Answer:     The Mongols
Question:   Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?
Answer:     Carthage
Question:   What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?
Answer:     Mustard Gas
Question:   What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?
Answer:     Beowulf
Question:   What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?
Answer:     Persia
Question:   Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?
Answer:     Saddam Hussein
Question:   What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?
Answer:     Marco Polo
Question:   What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?
Answer:     Tutankhamun
Question:   Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?
Answer:     Scotland
Question:   What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?
Answer:     Greek
Question:   For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?
Answer:     Tax Evasion
```

Answer (score 1):

you are initializing a *char array* with a list of string literals. What you want is an *array of pointers*.

For example:

```
   char *history[15] = { "Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III",
                         "Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther",
                         ...
```

And the same for other arrays.

Comment: I strongly recommend `const char *history[]` (and `-Wwrite-strings` if using gcc).

Comment: @melpomene You right, every decent compiler should have a FLAG to inform you that `const` should be present aka => `-Wwrite-strings` from `GCC`

Comment: @melpomene it is  a nuisance, generating zillions unneeded warnings. Thanks Godthat it was not addedto the Wall settings

Comment: @P__J__ What kind of code are you writing that is not const correct?

Comment: @melpomene even gcc authors have a very similar opinion :D

Comment: @P__J__ It's not a matter of opinion; `-Wwrite-strings` changes the type of string literals from `char [N]` to `const char [N]`, which is not compliant with the C standard (hence not the default). But it is useful in practice (and is exactly what C++ prescribes).